# How can i create a materialized view in apache geode?

Tags: gemfire, geode, spring-data-gemfire

I want to have value based on multiple joins between the table so how can i create a materialized view in apache geode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Geode is a high available in-memory data store, not a regular RDBMS system, so the "materialized view" concept doesn't even exist out of the box.

I guess you could simulate something by using `CacheListeners` and/or `CacheWriters` (see [here](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/19/developing/events/event_handler_overview.html)) to update an extra `Region` (using a newly created thread to avoid problems). A simpler option would be to use a `Function` (see [here](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/19/developing/function_exec/chapter_overview.html)) and simply calculate whatever you need directly on server side each time.

Either way, the actual implementation is highly tied to your use case and SLAs, so I'm not in a good position to recommend which option to use.

Cheers.